# Which oracle jdbc driver is my coldfusion 8 install using

Tags: coldfusion, oracle10g, coldfusion-8

I'm trying to debug a curious problem where by one coldfusion 8 instance is giving me an error (numeric or value error: character to number conversion error ORA-06512: at line 1) but with exactly the same code another coldfusion 8 instance isn't throwing the same error.

They are both on 8,0,1,195765  Enterprise, both running on Windows 2003.
I can't imagine why they might be using different drivers unfortunately I can't (without a huge faf) have them point to the same database.

I can (and have) modified the code so the error is no longer occurring, but I'm now trying to figure out what was going on.

So how do I find out what oracle jdbc driver ColdFusion is using, I found this blog post:
http://rahulnarula.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/getting-oracle-jdbc-driver-version-info.html
But that's only returning me no driver found.
If it helps both databases are using oracle 10g and both databases appear to be set up the same way (though I haven't ruled out that there maybe something there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try looking inside macromedia_drivers.jar for this file:
\macromedia\jdbc\oracle\oracle.properties
It looks like it contains the build ID for the Oracle driver.

Another approach would just be to diff macromedia-drivers.jar using beyond-compare or similar. It may not tell you what version the drivers are, but it will tell you whether they are the same.

Also, does the short, initial code block in the linked article not work? That ought to return something for the Macromedia drivers.

Barny

Comment: Thanks for that, they are using different drivers (buildid=016225 vs buildid=012821)